# fsck question/problem?

Tags: dual-boot, fsck

Dell Optiplex 2030, 16gb sdram, 2tb sata drive (two drives), 3.3GHz Quad core, Windows 7 and ubuntu 15.10 installed in a dual boot configuration using grub.  Two monitors.  (Yes, its a nice machine.)  Ubuntu is installed in /dev/sda5 with swap on /dev/sdb5

About two weeks ago (after 2 weeks of normal operation) during boot to ubuntu, I see the fsck message:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2

/dev/sda5: clean, 325837/1001712 files, 1515411/3999744 blocks
```

So far, so good, though I don't understand why it did not do it in the beginning.  (Maybe one of those "automatic" upgrades I let the system install?)

Now the problem...  About one week ago, I started getting two more lines of text following the above two:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2

/dev/sda5: clean, 325837/1001712 files, 1515411/3999744 blocks

[   19.983853] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found

[   19.983870] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

What is fsck telling me?  Is something wrong?  How do I fix it?  If nothing is wrong, what kind of errors would I be looking for?

Thank you.

Alex S

Comment: The two lines are kernel diagnostic messages and are unrelated to fsck. If the system boots properly, nothing is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

may be partition or DIsk on your system corruption. In this case is /dev/sdc .
please check and turn it out your system or fixed it, and try again. may be solve this problem

Comment: As far as I can tell, /dev/sdc is the USB memory stick I have in my computer.  It is always mounted.  I unmounted it and tried the boot again - no messages.  I remounted it - Still no messages.  Since then I have seen the messages once.  Can anyone tell me what the messages mean?  Thank you.  To recap, the messages are [   19.983853] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found

[   19.983870] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through

Comment: Update 2/17/2016 21:41 EST:  I h ave seen the extra two lines several times at boot.  This is intermixed with occasions of no lines.  I still would like an explanation as I don't understand kernel messages.  Thank you.